# Google Java API for AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp for web application

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, offline, credentials

I'm having some confusion with the API documentation and my use case, and how to handle the authorization token for my web application. I have a web service where users are signed into my application (not a Google app) and I need them to provide my service (Java with Spring Boot) authorization to upload for Youtube.  Later, I need to be able to use that authorization "offline" to upload videos to their channel, without them being logged into my service (an "auto publishing" type feature).  I've tried numerous methodologies, and generally have this working, but run into some bumps for clean implementation:

```
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes)
                        .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                        .setAccessType("offline")
                        .build();

        credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
```

Produces a console message with the url to provide the user to open in their browser.  I would have hoped the user would have be actually redirected.  I don't want this to be a manual process where I have to be at the console and then provide the user the url returned from this process for them to open in their own browser. The LocalServerReceiver, as I understand it, is for handling the actual access token response once authorization is given by the user.  I've explored this at length, and couldn't find any document solution or anything in the examples where this didn't produce a console message to the affect "paste the following url into your browser...." with the authorization url.

I tried using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow with:

```
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = (new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, scopes))
                .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();

        return flow.newAuthorizationUrl()
                .setScopes(scopes)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .setClientId(clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId())
                .setRedirectUri(redirectionUrl)
                .toString();
```

I put "/oauth2-callback" for my redirectionUrl, and this works (somewhat). I get the user to the Google authorization page, they authorize it and I get a token to my "callback" end point ("/oauth2-callback"), but that token doesn't appear to be fully authorized.  I store it in my data store ok, and see it there, but when I try to use it offline, I get an authorization error.  Going through more of the docs, I came upon this remaining code for handling the token sent back to my callback:

```
        GoogleTokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(token)
                .setRedirectUri(redirectUrl).execute();

        Credential credential = flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, "user");
```

The problem with this is that I'm already in my callback endpoint, and this wants another redirectURL.  The token from the authorization doesn't work in offline mode until I do this "newTokenRequest", which requires another redirect URL.  It appears to require the original redirectURL that was in the flow.newAuthorizationUrl() call, but when the newTokenRequest is executed, it produces another call back into that URL, and I end up getting a "token already redeemed" error.

In either of my scenarios above, with AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp, or using flow.newAuthorizationUrl() with a callback url that I handle with the token with flow.newTokenRequest and flow.createAndStoreCredential, I do get a credential I can use offline later.  But I'm having problem getting a smooth user experience in either one.

What am I missing in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation after you call `authorize` method, it calls `onAuthorization` method which eventually calls `browse` method using `authorizationUrl` to try to open browser automatically.

```
public static void browse(String url) {
Preconditions.checkNotNull(url);
// Ask user to open in their browser using copy-paste
System.out.println("Please open the following address in your browser:");
System.out.println("  " + url);
// Attempt to open it in the browser
try {
  if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
    if (desktop.isSupported(Action.BROWSE)) {
      System.out.println("Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...");
      desktop.browse(URI.create(url));
    }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Unable to open browser", e);
} catch (InternalError e) {
  // A bug in a JRE can cause Desktop.isDesktopSupported() to throw an
  // InternalError rather than returning false. The error reads,
  // "Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the
  // DISPLAY variable." The exact error message may vary slightly.
  LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Unable to open browser", e);
}
```

}

It should be inside try block where it tries to open a browser. Look for `Desktop.isDesktopSuported` `and desktop.isSupported(Action.BROWSE)` is true for the platform you run your program.

**Edit:** Above example is taken from Gmail service but oauth authorization flow is same for all Google products AFAIK.

Comment: With my service running under a tomcat on a server.  The Oracle Desktop utility class is part of the awt package which "allows a Java application to launch associated applications registered on the native desktop to handle a URI or a file."  Since this is running on a server, with a user connected via browser session through the servlet, which is making the AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(), I don't think there is a "native" desktop available, and that is why I get the console output.   It might be I can't use AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp for this??

Comment: The code above is  designed to run on client side. When you run it, it tries to open a browser but since you run it at server no browser is showing up. How do you pass result to clients if you are calling this at server side? And if a user connects to your system via a browser, you can change your design to run this authorization process at client side.

Comment: That was my "path 2".  In my narrative of initial post, start with "I tried using GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow with:...".  I went to getting authorization url and redirecting user to it, which works.  But followup handling of authcode causes second hit to callback url, giving me grief.  That's where my focus is right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party but just in case anyone else is still looking for a solution.  This approach works within the Vaadin framework.

Implement a custom browser and replace the default browser implementation.

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.Browser;
import com.vaadin.base.devserver.util.BrowserLauncher;

public class CustomBrowser implements Browser {

    public void browse(String url) {
        BrowserLauncher.launch(url, "Unable to open browser");
    }
}
```

[BrowserLauncher Javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/23.2.4/com/vaadin/base/devserver/util/BrowserLauncher.html) - under the hood it uses the Node JavaScript library.

Then replace the default browser with the custom browser.

```
credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver(), new CustomBrowser()).authorize("user");
```